# Reading pandas DataFrame with user defined indices

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame which needs to be processed in chunks as the file is big to be loaded entirely in the RAM.

For this, I used the following code:

```
chunk = pd.read_csv("file_name.csv", chunksize=5000)

type(chunk)
# pandas.io.parsers.TextFileReader

for c in chunk:
    print("chunk indices: {0}".format(c.index))
```

This gives the following ouput-

> chunk indices: RangeIndex(start=0, stop=5000, step=1)
>
> chunk indices: RangeIndex(start=5000, stop=10000, step=1)
>
> chunk indices: RangeIndex(start=10000, stop=15000, step=1)
>
> chunk indices: RangeIndex(start=15000, stop=20000, step=1)
>
> chunk indices: RangeIndex(start=20000, stop=25000, step=1)
>
> chunk indices: RangeIndex(start=25000, stop=30000, step=1)
>
> chunk indices: RangeIndex(start=30000, stop=35000, step=1)
>
> chunk indices: RangeIndex(start=35000, stop=40000, step=1)
>
> chunk indices: RangeIndex(start=40000, stop=45000, step=1)
>
> chunk indices: RangeIndex(start=45000, stop=45300, step=1)

However, I want that between the two successive chunks, there should be an overlap of user defined rows.

For example, if the "overlap" parameter = 50, then, the first chunk should go from 1 to 5000, the second chunk should start from (5000 - 50) 4950 to 10000, the third chunk should start from 9950 (10000 - 50) to 15000, the fourth chunk should start from 14500 (15000 - 50) to 20000 and so on.

How can I go about achieving this?

Thanks!